# Android SQLite query rows from bottom to top with timestamp to equal current date

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using SQLite for my app and I kind of have a large database. The database has 3 columns:

id(int auto incerement)|timestamp(int)|value(string)

I want to have the latest records, which have timestamp (millisec) of the current day.

At the I have a code to query all the records in the table, but it is awfully slow:

```
public List<PhysicalActivity> getAllPhysicalActivities(){
    List<PhysicalActivity> all = new ArrayList<PhysicalActivity>();

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(PhysicalActivityDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, mColumns
            , null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        PhysicalActivity pa = cursorToPhysicalActivity(cursor);
        all.add(pa);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return all;
}
```

I want to do `ORDER BY id DESC` as you would do in MySQL...I need to have something like this code:

```
public List<PhysicalActivity> getPhysicalActivitiesForDate(Date date){
    List<PhysicalActivity> activities = new ArrayList<PhysicalActivity>();

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(PhysicalActivityDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, mColumns
            , null, null, null, null, "ORDERBY " + PhysicalActivityDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + 
    " DESC");

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        PhysicalActivity pa = cursorToPhysicalActivity(cursor);
        Date d = new Date(pa.getTimestamp());
        if(d.getDay() == date.getDay()){
            activities.add(pa);
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return activities;
}
```

Another problem is that `getDay()` method is deprecated...what should I replace with that to have the same effect (compare the day the row's timestamp represents to the day in the date that passed as an argument).

Comment: `order by` requires whitespace inside

Comment: Try using a `CursorLoader`, it will run the query in a background thread and return the cursor. Although it will not speed up the query, the UI will atleast be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should solve your problem. I´ll explain it.

```
long curretTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
              PhysicalActivityDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, //Table name
              mColumns,                                  //Queryed columns
              PhysicalActivityDatabaseHelper.TIMESTAMP + " = " currentTime, //Select
              null, null, null,
              PhysicalActivityDatabaseHelper.TIMESTAMP + " DESC" //Order By
          );
```

First of all you're going to get the current time in milis so you can compare it. Then you'll retrieve all the fields of the table (only if you want), then you will retrieve only the rows matching the Select part and order that resulset in base of the Order By.

Hope it helps!